# How do I need to use Jquery UI Block

Tags: jquery

I have a button on the page in asp.net mvc control. when I click the button its taking some time to finish the work on my page.

Mean while If user wants to do something on the page I should not allow the user to do soo. So that I need to show the message please wait.

Is this the good idea to use jquery ui blcok? or do I need to do in other way?

If so how to do this kind of behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply disable the form and all interact-able elements if you think using a blocking API (such as blockUI) is overkill, e.g.:

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    $(this).find(':input').attr("disabled", "disabled");
});
```